# iOS ABPeoplePicker nav controller custom address book

Tags: ios

I'm having an issue with a peoplePicker nav controller. I'm trying to filter and show only contacts with email. This seems to work about halfway. Here's the code:

```
- (IBAction) addEmail: (id)sender {
    ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *picker;
    picker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];

    ABAddressBookRef test = [self getValidContacts];
    [picker setAddressBook:test];

    NSNumber* emailProp = [NSNumber numberWithInt:kABPersonEmailProperty];
    picker.displayedProperties = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:emailProp, nil];

    picker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;

    [parentController presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];

    [picker release];
}

- (ABAddressBookRef)getValidContacts{

    ABAddressBookRef allPeople = ABAddressBookCreate();
    ABAddressBookRef contactsWithEmail = ABAddressBookCreate();
    CFArrayRef allContacts = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(allPeople);
    CFIndex numberOfContacts = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(allPeople);
    CFErrorRef  anError = NULL; 

    for(int i=0; i<numberOfContacts;i++){
        ABRecordRef aPerson = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(allContacts, i);
        ABMultiValueRef emailProperty = ABRecordCopyValue(aPerson, kABPersonEmailProperty);
        if(ABMultiValueGetCount(emailProperty)>0){
            NSLog(@"this dude has an email address, he's on the list");
            //ABAddressBookAddRecord(contactsWithEmail, aPerson, &anError);
       }
        else{
            NSLog(@"this guy has no email, removing them from the addressBook");
            ABAddressBookRemoveRecord(contactsWithEmail, aPerson, &anError);
        }

    }
    int foo = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(contactsWithEmail);
    NSLog(@"at the end we have %d contacts with email", foo);
    return contactsWithEmail;
}
```

I'm testing this in simulator with 4 contacts: 3 have one or more email addresses, and one doesn't. It seems that my getValidContacts method does what its supposed to do... it returns an address book with only the 3 contacts that have email properties. When the peoplePicker table comes up though, the 4th guy is still there. If I select the cell that shouldn't exist I get a SIGABRT error, like I'm trying to touch a deallocated object.

I've read that saving the modified addressBook will alleviate my problems, but I'm not crazy about the prospect of deleting other peoples' contacts. Am I thinking about it wrong? if I create an addressBook and save it will it modify the shared addressBook on the device?

Anybody have any success filtering the addressBook for specific contacts that can instruct me a bit?

thanks in advance.

Comment: any luck with this? I'm trying to do something similar with only Exchange GAL contacts.

Comment: no, I've ran it past about a half dozen more experienced iOS devs and we came to the conclusion that this is just buggy behavior. I suppose you could probably take that custom address book and run it through your own peoplePicker, but I'm not sure Apple would allow it.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I started a more general question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10016545/572954) to see what kind of info I can gather.  In the mean time, I've been searching for OWA api's that can be used from inside an iOS app.